# Mangling and static/dynamic binding in visual studo 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For C++ class can I see the intermediate compilation stage/s? : variable/methods mangling?
some readable representation of generated code for static binding ? vtable?
for students

Comment: Not sure if it covers everything you have in mind, but [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/) kinda goes there and is pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

VS ILDasm is a tool that can decompile code. You could add ILDasm in VS.
Here are the steps:

1. Select `Tools->External Tools->ILDasm`
2. Select the path of ILDasm.exe in `Command`. The path is generally `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vXXX\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\ildasm.exe`.
3. Type `$(TargetPath) /text/item:` in `Arguments`, then click `Apply`